# '{' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python

Running on Windows, the following Python program produces the above output (the content of the output variable)

```
import commands

cmd = "dir"
(output) = commands.getoutput(cmd)
print output
```

Very interesting and frustrating. Can someone point me to the explanation please?

Comment: Consider using `subprocess` instead of `commands`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html#commands.getstatusoutput):

> cmd is actually run as { cmd ; } 2>&1

Which is where the `{` are coming from.  You should use `subprocess` instead.

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['dir'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
```

The `shell=True` is required in this specific case as dir is an internal DOS command. Normally one should provide full path to the executable and keep shell disabled.

Comment: The docs also note that the `commands` module is for Unix platforms only

Comment: @Ber -- I suppose this would be why :).

Comment: @Ber I only see the Unix word in the online docs not the one I get in the REPL while using Windows :)  thanks anyway!

Comment: @defuz -- Thanks for the edit.  I don't have a windows machine, so I didn't know any of that (but I'm trusting you with my SO rep ;-)